# How can I have a single goroutine function that waits for values from multiple others?

Tags: multithreading, go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

I've created a [Go playground sample](https://play.golang.org/p/Qikj0KUbKf_h) that illustrates what I'm talking about.

In the example, I create one goroutine, func2, which I would simply like to wait for inputs through its channel and print the value once it arrives.

```
func func2(ch chan int) {
    fmt.Println("func2")
    v:=<-ch
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Then, in a loop, I create goroutines for another function, and these are part of a WaitGroup.

```
func func1(ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Println("func1")
    ch <- 11032
    wg.Done()
}
```

And in main, I wait for the WaitGroup. I'm running into a deadlock and I'm not sure how to fix it. Just so it's clear what I'm trying to achieve, I want func2 to stay open as a thread once I call it, to process n values, where n is the number of goroutines I call for func1. I considered using a WaitGroup Wait inside of func2, but I don't want it blocking, as it needs to process new data from func1 as it's sent.

Comment: Let func2 `range` over `ch` until closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting a deadlock because your `func2` is consuming only **1** value from `ch` and then finishing. Then the other `func1` goroutines are stuck waiting for `ch` to be available to write into, which they cannot do because there is no other goroutine to read from `ch` on the other end.

Since you want `func2` to continually consume values from `ch` until `ch` is closed, you need to create a loop in `func2` like so:

```
func func2(ch chan int) {
    fmt.Println("func2")
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

This will keep `func2` "alive" and reading from `ch` until you do `close(ch)` somewhere else. The appropriate place to close `ch` in your example would likely be in `main` after `wg.Wait()`.

If you want to be sure to see the results from all `Println` statements before the program finishes, you should also use some synchronization mechanism to wait for `func2` to finish. Otherwise `main` will end immediately after `close(ch)` which *may or may not* be before `func2` has printed every value it received.

A common technique for this is a "done" channel. For example:

```
func func2(ch chan int, done chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("func2")
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    done <- true
}
```

and in `main`:

```
done := make(chan bool)
go func2(ch, done)
...
wg.Wait()
close(ch)
<-done
```

Using `chan struct{}` (empty struct) is also very common since empty struct requires no memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a clean way to close the channels when all the values have finished streaming through. When new values come in, you may create a new channel and start streaming values on this. This is the way I do it, maybe it helps

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

toUpdate := make(chan *someType, BufferSize)

for i := 0; i < BufferSize; i++ {
    go processEvents(toUpdate, &wg)
}

// // wait till all the checks have come back
go func(toUpdate chan * someType, group *sync.WaitGroup) {
    group.Wait()
    close(toCreate)
}(toCreate, toUpdate, &wg)
```